# In Django Combobox choices, how do you lookup description from short value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In Django models/forms the choices for a combobox often look like this:

```
food_choices = (("",""), ("1", "Falafel"), ("2", "Hummus"), ("3", "Eggplant Stuff, Babaganoush???"),
```

So the value to be stored in the database will be 1/2/3, but the displayed value on the form will be the long description.  When we are working in code outside a form, how can we quickly lookup the long description given the short value stored in the model?

So I want to map short values to long values:

```
>>print foo("1")
  "Falafel"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`get_FOO_display()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: +1 - but note that this is only useful if you need to get the value "Falafel" from a model instance.

Comment: Working link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display